# Function for certain values in rows

Tags: r

I have a paneldata which looks like:

(Only the substantially cutting for my question)

```
Persno 122 122 122 333 333 333 333 333 444 444 
Income 1500 1500 2000 2000 2100 2500 2500 1500 2000 2200
year 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 1 2
```

I need a command or function to recognize the different Person. For all rows with the same Person I would like to give out the average income.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Consider reading the very good manuals, in particular paragraph 4.2 of the "Introduction to R manual" at http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#The-function-tapply_0028_0029-and-ragged-arrays

Comment: This look like homework, if is so please read this http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/

Comment: Thank you Andrie an Vash for the useful link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite tool to solve problems like this is ddply, in the plyr package.

```
 library(plyr)
 p = pdata.frame(data.frame(year=rep(c(1,2,3),3), persno = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), income=c(1500,1500,2000,2000,2100,2500,2500,1500,2000)))
 dply(p, .(persno), summarize, mean.income = mean(income))
```

which gives us the output

```
  persno mean.income
  1      1    1666.667
  2      2    2200.000
  3      3    2000.000
```

Comment: Can I also give out the range of the worked years? For each persno.

Comment: @Andre - you can calculate more than one thing at a time in the command above, so something like `ddply(p, .(persno), summarize, mean.income = mean(income), yrwork = max(year) - min(year))` should give you what you want.